# vba MS Word: Printing to multiple paper trays

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I am trying to implement a vba script to print invoices on multiple colors of paper given a certain scenario to a different printer than the system default.  Hence, I need to print page 1 to the middle paper tray and print page 1 again to the lower paper tray both to a "Brother HL" printer.

I have the following code:

```
Sub PrintInvoice()

Dim sDefaultPrinter As String
Dim sInvoicePrinter As String

sInvoicePrinter = "Brother HL-L5200DW series"
sDefaultPrinter = Application.ActivePrinter
Application.ActivePrinter = sInvoicePrinter


With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .PaperSize = wdPaperLetter
    .FirstPageTray = wdPrinterUpperBin
End With

    Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Item:= _
        wdPrintDocumentContent, Copies:=1, Pages:="1-1", PageType:= _
        wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, PrintToFile:=False, PrintZoomColumn:=0, _
        PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0

Application.ActivePrinter = sDefaultPrinter

End Sub
```

However, my problem is two fold:

1. I cannot get the printer to switch to the Brother HL is print the invoices without setting the system default.  I receive:

```
Run-time error '4232':  The FilePrintSetup command is not available in Word.
```

when trying to execute Application.ActivePrinter = sInvoicePrinter

2. I cannot set the tray because I receive the following fatal error when I run the script.

```
Run-time error '5518':

Increasing left margin causes first column to become too narrow in some sections having unevenly spaced columns.
```

And guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

M

I have tried ActivePrinter and PrintOut commands

Comment: Printing is primarily under the control of the operating system, not Word. In Windows, you could include system calls in your code to do this. In macOS, it's easier to use AppleScript. Here's a page with a couple of sample scripts, there are many others out there: https://www.macscripter.net/t/applescript-to-switch-printers/69902/4 Here is Ron de Bruin's page on using AppleScript in VBA: https://macexcel.com/examples/setupinfo/applescripttask/